# How to dynamically add columns with same name on a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a list of emails, phones and user info that I want to output in csv but I need to follow a format that contains duplicate columns.

```
email, email, phone, phone, phone, name, address
jo@doe.com, re@ko.com, 90192, 2980, 9203, John Doe, 82 High Street
re@doe.com, az@ko.com, 1341, 55, 665, Roe Jan, 11 Low Street
red@doe.com,,, 55, 111, Roe Jan, 11 Low Street
```

Is this possible in pandas? What is the best way of adding rows and columns with same name?

Comment: You can not have duplicate column names in `pandas`

Comment: Assuming you want the output in csv for viewing it in excel or similiar, you could add blank spaces after the key phone. E.g. "phone", "phone ", "phone  ". But why not label the columns based on the different use case of each phone-number?

Comment: @f.wue I cannot label them differently, I have no choice but to follow their format that contains duplicate names

Answer (score 1):

You could get it done using `csv`:

list.txt:

```
email, email, phone, phone, phone, name, address
jo@doe.com, re@ko.com, 90192, 2980, 9203, John Doe, 82 High Street
re@doe.com, az@ko.com, 1341, 55, 665, Roe Jan, 11 Low Street
red@doe.com,,, 55, 111, Roe Jan, 11 Low Street
```

and then:

```
import csv

with open('list.txt', 'r') as readFile:
    reader = csv.reader(readFile)
    lines = list(reader)

with open('people.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(lines)

readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

OUTPUT (people.csv):

[image: out]

Answer (score 1):

Build your dataframe with different column names (email01, email02...) and then use a header list on output:

```
df.to_csv("file.csv",header=['email', 'email', 'phone', 'phone', 'phone', 'name', 'address'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.conact to add columns with the same name:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

It will concatenate all columns, even if some of them have the same name.